# How to find horizontal shear interpetetion.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $ \vec{x}=\left[ \begin{array}{c} x_1\\ x_2\\ \end{array} \right] $ and $T$ is vertical shear transformation. Formula for the sheared vector is
$$T(\vec{x})=T\left(\left[\begin{array}{l}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{array}\right]\right)=\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
k x_1+x_2
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
k & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
k & 1
\end{array}\right] \vec{x}$$  Illustrate

[image]

Point $R = (x_1, 0)$ then $P = (x_1, kx_1) $

$|PR| = kx_1$

Let $K$ is horizontal shear transformation. Formula for the sheared vector is
$$K(\vec{x})=K\left(\left[\begin{array}{l}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{array}\right]\right)=\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_1+n x_2 \\
x_2
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & n \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & n \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \vec{x}$$

[image]

**Question**
Does the picture describe the transformation well.
Where is segment $x_1+n x_2$ or $n x_2$ ?